# How do I write $\notin$ backwards?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I write `$P \niton x$`, but it does not work. How can I write the symbol `$\notin$` backwards?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more bizarre if it actually worked? :)

Comment: Do you want the slash to be backwards too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After consulting [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) a few fonts provide such a symbol:

- `txfonts`, `newtxmath` and `pxfonts` have `$\notni$`.
- `mathabx` has `$\notowner$` and `$\varnotowner$`
- `MnSymbol` has `$\nowns$`
- `mathdesign` has a small version `$\notsmallowns$`, but no normal sized one.
- `kpfonts` has `$\notowns$`

Note however that using one of these packages changes the complete font set. Of course you can rip this single symbol from a font that has it, let's try with `$\notni$` from txfonts, surrounded by Latin Modern:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\notniFromTxfonts}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{61}
...
$x \notin P \notniFromTxfonts x$
```

but the result is not convincing:

[image: notni]

Comment: You should remark that both these packages change the whole font, not only add some symbols.

Answer (score 33):

If the math fonts you use don't have the symbol, you can say

```
\newcommand{\niton}{\not\owns}
```

Here's a complete example, showing that the symbol will change size in subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\niton}{\not\owns}
\begin{document}
$A\niton x_{B\niton y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your fonts don't have `\owns` (that is, the reverse of `\in`) you can emulate it by loading `graphicx` and `amsmath`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\niton}{\not\mathrel{\text{\reflectbox{$\in$}}}}
```

---

A possibly better definition, that uses the same slash as `\notin`, can be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\niton{\mathrel{\m@th\mathpalette\canc@l\owns}}
\newcommand\canc@l[2]{{\ooalign{$\hfil#1/\mkern1mu\hfil$\crcr$#1#2$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$A\niton x_{B\niton y}$

$A\notin x_{B\notin y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some `\m@th` would probably be good.

Comment: @HenriMenke Isn't it there in the “better definition”?

Comment: Oh, yes indeed it is there.  But it is missing from the `\reflectbox` example.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

$\notin$ \reflectbox{$\notin$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not work for me. It just prints the same symbol without reversing it.
I have a \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} and I use TeXnicCenter 1 RC1 and Tex 3.1n15926 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit.

Comment: view the pdf output and not the dvi one!

Answer (score 8):

I believe that `\rotatebox` is more proper than `\reflectbox`, I suggest this solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@notni[2]{\mathrel{\rotatebox[y=#1]{180}{$#2\notin$}}}
\newcommand\notni{
\mathchoice
  {\@notni{0.57ex}\displaystyle}
  {\@notni{0.57ex}\textstyle}
  {\@notni{0.39ex}\scriptstyle}
  {\@notni{0.26ex}\scriptscriptstyle}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
    L\notni x
\quad
    x\notin L
\quad
    \sum_{L\notni x} f(L)
\quad
    \sum_{Z_{L\notni x}} 1
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry to disagree, but i think `\reflectbox` is the correct interpretation here -- it's a mirror image.  the only situation in which i'd use `\rotatebox` is if the symbol were sloped, and the slope had to be retained.  (this is done, for example, with the first `E` in `\XeTeX` when it's rendered in italic; see `ltugboat.cls`.)  but `\in` is usually symmetrical, and besides, `\owns` (= `\ni`) is defined in `plain.tex`, so should be available in any good tex system.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tried to place them next to each other: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXwr.png and I came to conclusion that having all the slashes "forward" is more consistent; on any other symbol the slash is this way, so why should `\ni` be an exception?

Comment: ah -- i was considering just the basic `\in` as being rotated.  apologies.  i didn't read your code carefully enough, but rashly assumed that you were rotating the non-negated symbol and then applying `\not`.  in this case you're correct; rotation is appropriate.  but still better to use `\owns` directly.  no need then for `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well, the pointe is whether you want to manually adjust vertical placement of the symbol (as I do) or horizontal placement of the `\not` (as **egreg** does).

Answer (score 1):

my solution is: `$\ni \negthickspace \negthickspace \negthickspace / $`
or`$\owns \negthickspace \negthickspace \negthickspace /$`
at least on my page it worked fine.

Comment: this one is slightly more slanted than \not (in default font), but I'm not sure if it's desirable especially if all the other ones have equal slant. / side note, this may mess the spacing after the character up / the 3 repetition is equivalent to `\mskip -3\thickmuskip`

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

> $\not\ni$

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, anywhere `\ni` is defined `\owns` should be defined, so this should be identical to egreg's answer.